# Iterators from the same ViewObject do not communicate

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0
I am facing a strange behavior here. I have created 2 AppModules and in each AppModule I have DataControls from the same View Object (not only but also). When I create a new row using Page1 for example using DataControl from AppModule1 and then navigate to Page2 that uses DataControl from AppModule2, the Commit and Rollback buttons are enabled. Even if I redeploy the application in this case I have to Commit also in Page2. If I do this, then the problem will not show any more.
So even through I commit in the first case, I have to commit also in the second page. As I said the EO and VO are the same, just the AppModules are different.
Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix this?
If anyone knows that this is a known bug please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I hurried a little, I just found the solution (the problem actually). Apparently different app modules are completely ignored one by other and have their own db connections. The explanations is here: 
http://www.jobinesh.com/2010/03/what-you-may-need-to-know-about-nested.html

Comment: I do believe if you nest application modules, they will share the same db connection.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is a little strange actually that even if I redeploy the application the problem is the same. It maybe means that each App Module contains some inner keys in some file and finds that a certain record is in the database and he is not aware so it shows the commit option because "thinks" that the user just added those..